# Can't output Awk to variable, says permission is denied

Tags: bash

I have the following code that results in a "Permission denied" error. It is supposed to get the nth word of a string and store it to a variable. If I use it with echo, it works just fine, but produces the error when trying to save it to a variable.

```
a="one two three four five six"
N=2
b=$($a | awk -v N=$N '{print $N}')
echo $b
```

What could the problem be?

Comment: Heh. The reason you probably couldn't find any duplicates for this is that most often `$a` isn't a valid file or command name, so people making the same mistake usually get "file not found". In your case I'm assuming your real data is not `"one two three four five six"` but the name of a file that doesn't have executable permission, hence "permission denied".

Comment: ... That's part of why it's important to test that even after you anonymized your data your code still gives the error you're asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `echo` for variable printing like as follows:

```
a="one two three four five six"
N=2
b=$(echo "$a" | awk -v N=$N '{print $N}')
echo $b
```

OR use like `<<<"$var"` for sending input to `awk` command:

```
a="one two three four five six"
N=2
b=$(awk -v N=$N '{print $N}' <<<"$a")
echo $b
```

When we are running command without `echo` it is considered as a command which is NOT so we get error like `line 3: one: command not found` so to send Input to `awk` command use anyone of the above mentioned commands.